# Категории новостей. SQL

Tags: php, sql

Есть новостной сайт. У каждой новости есть категории. Категории делятся на футболистов, команды и чемпионаты. То есть, 3 разные таблицы. При чем новость может одновременно входить в разные категории. Например, чемпионат + несколько футболистов + несколько команд. Как это можно организовать?

Comment: Связь `многие ко многим`...

Comment: То есть создать таблицу, которая будет содержать 5 колонок с id, player, team и турнир + id новости? И если категория повторяется создавать еще одну запись? Пример не помешал бы..

Comment: Опишите задачу подробнее. Что за 3 таблицы, какое они имеют отношение к категориям. В общепринятом смысле у категории есть только наименование и конечно все категории могут быть в 1 таблице а не в 3. То что новость входит в некие категории это обычная практика. но вот как новость соотносится с игроками, чемпионатами и прочее распишите

Comment: Три таблицы: игроки(имя, дата рождения, национальность и тд), чемпионаты(название, лого), команды(название, лого, год основания и тд). Вот эти 3 таблицы и должны быть категориями новостей. Есть таблица новости. И нужно как-то связать каждую новость с определенными категориями. Как я выше писал, новость может одновременно входить в разные категории. Например, чемпионат + несколько футболистов + несколько команд.

Comment: что означает "эти таблицы должны быть категориями". Категория выглядит как "Игрок" (любой) или как много категорий вроде "Игрок Иванов", "Игрок Петров"

Comment: Второй вариант.

Comment: Я бы это назвал субъекты новости. Ну ладно, терминология роли не играет. Я бы сделал общую таблицу "Категории новостей (субъекты), в которой были бы всего 2 поля ID и тип(Игрок, Чемпионат, Команда). При добавлении записи в любую из 3х таблиц я бы сначала добавлял запись в Категории с соотв. типом и id для записи в основной таблице брал от только что вставленной. (т.е. эти 3 таблицы все зависимые и автоинкремента своего в них нет, первичный ключ по id является так же и внешним на категории)...

Comment: После чего делается стандартная связующая таблица многие-ко-многим. Т.е. состоящая всего из 2х полей id-новости, id-категории

Comment: Если на общие id эти 3 таблицы переводить уже поздно, то можно пойти другим путем. только связующая таблица, но из 3х полей: id-новости, Код-категории (игрок/команда/чемпионат), id-субъекта (соответствующий id из одной из 3х таблиц)

Comment: А что такое код-категории (игрок/команда/чемпионат)? Это отдельная таблица или просто поля с названиями?

Comment: поля с чем нибудь. названия целиком я бы не писал, место незачем занимать, сделал бы что то вроде P/T/C. главное что бы вы знали что какая буква значит, что бы в запросе где будут таблицы с названиями/именами цепляться в условиях задавать

Comment: Тоже была мысль такой тип связи сделать. Но если три игрока, как выше писал или два клуба, то надо будет замарочиться с поиском по ним, что игрок 10 не был игроком 110, и писать не просто ид, а например p10,p110 и искать или через char_index() like(%p10,%)
Даже таблица post|club|player|champ, где через запятую можно указать все ид, кто входит, то всё равно тоже самое с игроком 10 и 110, и надо дописи делать + поиск по строке тяжелее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из того, что вы написали возможно так

```
create table posts (
    id   identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    name varchar(255)  not null,
    ...
);

create table champs (
    id   identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    name varchar(255)  not null,
    ...
);

create table clubs (
    id   identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    name varchar(255)  not null,
    ...
);

create table players (
    id   identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    name varchar(255)  not null,
    ...
);


create table posts_champs_links (
    post_id  int not null foreign key references posts (id),
    champ_id int not null foreign key references champs (id)
);
create table posts_clubs_links (
    post_id int not null foreign key references posts (id),
    club_id int not null foreign key references clubs (id)
)
create table posts_players_links (
    post_id   int not null foreign key references posts (id),
    player_id int not null foreign key references players (id)
);
```

Comment: Так это получается, что новость придется дублировать, если она связанна с несколькими категориями.

Comment: Если это реляционная бд, то дублирование есть, но это дублирование ИД новости, а не самой новости.
Если у тебя в посту: 1 клуб, 2 футболиста, 1 чемпионат
То будет: 
posts - 1 row
players - 2 row
champ - 1 rown

Когда в поиске перейдут на страницу по игрокам, и выберут игрока, например Messi
Из таблицы players у него id = 98
Сделаешь запрос в posts_players_links по полю player_id
Получишь posts_id
Сделаешь запрос в posts c джоином к выбранной таблице
И получишь все посты с ним
Отсортируешь от недавнего до давнего и выведешь

Comment: А это нормально, что мы будем создавать сначала 3 таблицы с игроками, чемпионатами и клубами, а потом с помощью отдельных таблиц связывать их с новостями? Никаким правилам не противоречит?

Comment: Не вижу, что может этому противоречить.

Comment: Ну а если у меня еще таблица с тренерами есть. Опять создавать связующую таблицу?

Comment: Если по такому способу, то да. Промежуточная таблица - это как карта связей. Второй способ писал в комментариях вопроса
`post_id|team|players|champs|...(new category)`
`1|t1,|p1,p2,|c1,c2,|...`
или
`post_id|categories`
`1|t1,p1,p2,c1,c2,`

поиск будет внутри по полям отдельно или вместе
`select * from tbl where categories like '%c1,%' or like '%p2,%' or ...`

Comment: [Вот нашёл ссылку по тегам](http://howto.philippkeller.com/2005/04/24/Tags-Database-schemas/)

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.